# C# method rollDice

Tags: c#

Hi need to write a program that Given a method rollDice() which simulates rolling a dice by returning a random value between 1 and 6, write a condition for the while loop in the code below so that it will end after a double 6 has been rolled (i.e. both dice have the value 6):need youre help.

```
    using System;
{
  class Program;
  {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        while ( a==6; b==6)
        {
          a = rollDice();
          b = rollDice();
          Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",a,b);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `while(a == 6 || b == 6)`?

Comment: @FCin how does that stop after a double 6 has been rolled?

Comment: @MottiCohen what have you tried so far?

Comment: @FCin should be `&&` imho. @MottiCohen: It's required to explicitly state your problem. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: @TimothyGroote I'm just pointing out that his code does not even compile...

Comment: @FCin i think OP knows that, since it appears to be part of his assignment ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're asking us to do your homework

Comment: So you have to loop while either `a != 6` or `b != 6` i.e. `while (a != 6 || b != 6) {...}` an alternative is `while (!(a == 6 && b == 6)) {...}`

Comment: Please read [ask] and explicitly state what part exactly you require help with, and what you have tried. This code yields a couple of compiler errors to begin with, which you haven't mentioned in your question. Don't expect us to write the code for you.

Comment: `while (a != 6 && b != 6)` done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:
Changed the while to a do-while, as this will always execute once, regardless of the initial value of a or b. It's up to your preferences if you want to do it like this or with a while.

Next to that, I have changed the parameters of the while from while (a == 6 ; b ==6) to while(!(a == 6 && b ==6).

First of all, the ; in OP's post is syntactically incorrect, and won't work. It checks if a and/or b is 6 (depending on if the ; was supposed to be a || or a &&), and if it is, continues. That is the opposite of the desired effect, as OP wanted the loop to stop when both are 6.

`while(!(a == 6 && b ==6)` will check if both are 6, and if so it will stop the loop. If either is not 6, the loop will continue.

Try this:

```
int a;
int b;
//Do while because I'm assuming you always want to roll the dice at least once
    do 
    {
        a = rollDice();
        b = rollDice();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",a,b);
    } while (!(a == 6 && b == 6));
```

This will roll the dice until both are 6, as asked

Comment: You dumped working code without explaining what it does. That's not a good answer in general, and especially not when the OP is still learning. They also have their code right in the class, not in a method. Answers shouldn't be upvoted just because they contain working code, especially not to questions like this.

Comment: In OP´c case a while-loop will do anyway, as he´s initializing `a` and `b` with zero, whereas the loop checks for six. Thus it *will* execute at least once.

Comment: @CodeCaster updated my answer to explain my changes.

Answer (score -2):

The answer below is incorrect, as it won't stop if you roll the sequence, for instance, 3 6 6.

My suggestion would be to keep one variable for storing the previous roll result, then call `rollDice()` - stop if the result is 6 and the previous roll was also 6, otherwise assign the new value to the "previous roll" variable and continue the loop.

Comment: They roll two dice at once.

Comment: OP *allways* rollls two dices, so there´s no sequence.

Comment: Well yes it says *both* dice must have the value 6, but it never actually says you have to roll both at once...

Comment: If you really just wanted to simulate rolling two at the same time until a double 6 is achieved you might as well just have `while (Math.Random(0,36) != 35);`!

Comment: @DylanNicholson That´s obvious from OPs code. Within one iteration two dices are rolled.

Comment: If there's anything I've  learned from stackoverflow, nothing's *ever* obvious  from the OPs code! He may well have misunderstood the original requirements.

Answer (score -3):

Or try this:

```
for (int a = rollDice(), b = rollDice(); a + b < 12; a = rollDice(), b = rollDice())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", a, b);
}
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", 6, 6);
```

Comment: This is not the kind of answer you want to show a beginner since it misuses language features and is missing any explanation.