# While loop until two vars have the same number

Tags: java, while-loop

Given a method rollDice() which simulates rolling a dice by returning a random value between 1 and 6, write a condition for the while loop in the code below so that it will end after a double 6 has been rolled (i.e. both dice have the value 6):

```
int dice1 = 0;
int dice2 = 0;

while (/*what kind of condition do I need here?*/)
{
  dice1 = rollDice();
  dice2 = rollDice();
  System.out.println("You rolled " + dice1 + " and " + dice2);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a homework help request.

Comment: Sure is, seems whoever is giving them homeworks gives the same every year. The question was asked and answered before, using exactly same sentences. -1-ing the question due to lack of any effort in solving the problem/looking for a solution himself.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450483/c-sharp-method-rolldice

Answer (score 1):

First, `0` isn't a valid value; so test if either `dice` is `0`; or that they aren't equal.

```
while (dice1 == 0 || dice1 != dice2)
```

Read it like *while `dice1` is zero, or `dice1` is not equal to `dice2`*.

Answer (score 1):

The condition you are looking for is `(dice1!=6||dice2!=6)`.

As complete code:

```
 int dice1;
 int dice2;
 do{
    dice1 = rollDice();
    dice2 = rollDice();
 }while((dice1!=6||dice2!=6));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
while (dice1 != dice2) {
    ...
}
```

but you would have to change the initial values of `dice1` and `dice2` so they are different.